# How to upload images using modal in codeigniter and insert into database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

**SOLVED read my comment below**

So i want to upload image using modal in codeigniter, the answer is right in front of my eyes, it's right on this link https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html, but the thing is, on that web it only display an action form upload that not using any modal and not insert it into any database, i already try it but since i'm not good at coding and not to mention just learned how to use codeigniter like yesterday, so i hardly understand how to implement it using modal in codeigniter

The thing is i already did few ways to make it happen but its seems that my modal get an error

so here is the code

**CONTROLLER**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Barang extends CI_Controller{
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->model('Crud');
}

public function index(){
    $data['tab3'] = true; 
    $data['query'] = $this->Crud->read('barang', null, 'idbarang', 'DESC');
    $this->load->view('admin/barang_halaman', $data);
}

//insert data into database
public function insert(){
    $nama = $this->input->post('namaBarang');
    $harga = $this->input->post('harga');
    $stock = $this->input->post('stock');
    $idkategori = $this->input->post('kategori');
    //====================================================================
    //$img is a variable to put the image that has been inputed
    //====================================================================
    $img= $this->input->post('foto');
    $data = array('nama'=>$nama, 'harga'=>$harga, 'stock'=>$stock, 'idkategori'=>$idkategori,'foto'=>$img);
    $insert = $this->Crud->create('barang', $data);
    redirect(($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']), 'refresh');
}

//========================================================================
//upload image
//source of this code i got it from the link that i already provide above, but i don't know how to use it
//========================================================================
public function do_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '500';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('filename'))
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
    }
}
```

}

and here is my view

**VIEW**

```
<!-- Insert data using modal -->
    <div id="addModal" class="modal fade" role="modal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h3 class="modal-title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Tambah Barang</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form action="<?php echo site_url('admin/barang/insert');?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        
                        //==================================================
                        //Heres the code that i use in codeigniter to upload images, 
                        //but it's seems i'm getting error using this code
                        //==================================================
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Foto</label>
                            <input type="file" name="foto" id="foto" class="form-control" action="<?php echo site_url('admin/barang/do_upload');?>">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:100%;">Tambah</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Insert data using modal end-->
```

below is the error that i get, i believes its because the query or the function that somehow i don't know how to use it.

> Error Number: 1048
>
> Column 'foto' cannot be null
>
> INSERT INTO `barang` (`nama`, `harga`, `stock`, `idkategori`, `foto`) VALUES ('Meja Baru', '10000', '5', '2', NULL)
>
> Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/PWI/tubes/AKS-master/application/models/Crud.php
>
> Line Number: 11

Comment: so what is output?? or error??

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: kindly check my edited question again

Comment: @wogsland, thanks im going to edit it and make it simple as possible

Comment: it was my mistake, i put a wrong name in the query and also in the controller, also i forgot to input the result into the query i forgot to use the semicolon at the end of some of my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I handle the upload process. But I think your problem is with your MYSQL table settings. Check if the foto field has the allow Null setting set. You might not be able to set the foto value to null and the database is throwing the error you are getting.

The Controller function:

```
public function save_file() {       
    $config['upload_path']          = './accounts/uploads';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'jpg|jpeg|png';
    $config['max_size']             = 500;
    $config['max_width']            = 1600;
    $config['max_height']           = 1600;
    $config['encrypt_name']         = TRUE;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('file')){
        //upload was not successful
    }else {
        //upload was successful
        $this->load->model('products_model');

        $photo_data['account_id'] = $this->account_id;
        $photo_data['product_id'] = $this->input->post('record_id');
        $photo_data['file_name'] = $this->upload->data('file_name');
        $photo_data['file_type'] = $this->upload->data('file_type');
        $photo_data['file_path'] = $this->upload->data('file_path');
        $photo_data['full_path'] = $this->upload->data('full_path');
        $photo_data['raw_name'] = $this->upload->data('raw_name');
        $photo_data['orig_name'] = $this->upload->data('orig_name');
        $photo_data['file_ext'] = $this->upload->data('file_ext');
        $photo_data['file_size'] = $this->upload->data('file_size');
        $photo_data['is_image'] = $this->upload->data('is_image');
        $photo_data['image_width'] = $this->upload->data('image_width');
        $photo_data['image_height'] = $this->upload->data('image_height');
        $photo_data['image_type'] = $this->upload->data('image_type');
        $photo_data['image_size_str'] = $this->upload->data('image_size_str');

        $this->products_model->add_product_photo($photo_data);
    }
}
```

Then the Model Function Looks like this.

```
public function add_product_photo($photo_data){
    $this->db->insert('product_photos_tbl', $photo_data);
    $product_photo_id = $this->db->insert_id();

    return $product_photo_id;
}
```

Comment: that is seems like a lot of work, and that just same like mine but in the succesful section you declare bunch of stuffs, is that necessary? can we make it simple?

Comment: @MirzaChilman I separated them all out to make it easy to see what was being sent to the model and ultimately to the db table. Yes you could just pass the upload array in one simple line of code, but that would assume you have all the appropriate fields in your db table otherwise you would get an error from the db. the code would look like $photo_data = $this->upload->data();

Comment: well this code actually work, i just cut something that i don't need, thnks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Your selected file name will not come in post array. It will be present in `$_FILES` array

To get the name of the selected image,

```
 $img= $_FILES['foto']['name'];// this will have original name
```

And where in `insert()` you are calling `do_upload()` to upload the file.

Comment: in the "View" there is a div with a class "modal-body" there i calling the insert function, while do_upload function, i'm not quite sure how to use that function,

Comment: ok i already do what you told me, and it is work, there are no error and the image succesfuly uploaded to the database but, the image not showing up in any folders any idea why? maybe because the "do_upload()" function not been called properly?

Comment: in `$this->upload->do_upload('file')` 'file' is the name of the file from post. for example: if you get this on server side like `$_FILES['foto']` in do_upload should be `$this->upload->do_upload('foto');`